# Is 0-initialization of atomics guaranteed to set the value member to 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer, atomic

What does 0-initialization of `std::atomic<integral_type>` variable mean?

Origins of the question. I have a function-static `std::array` of `std::atomic<std::int>`, which I want to be set to 0 before the first use (goes without saying, function where the array resides is called in unpredictable manner from multiple threads).

This piece of code is good-looking, but not compiling due to atomics being non-copy constructable:

```
#include <array>
#include <atomic>

void foo() {
    using t = std::atomic<int>;
    static std::array<t, 2> arr = {0, 0}; // <-- explicit, but errors out (see below)
    static std::array<t, 2> arr2; // <-- implicit?, works
}
```

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic::atomic(const std::atomic&)’
>   std::array arr = {0, 0};

Now, I understand that static `std::array` is going to 0-initialize all it's members, and `std::atomic<>` is going to be 0-initialized. But do we have an explicit or implicit gurantee that it will actually set all **values** to 0? Common sense says 'yes' - after all, we assume the class would have a member of type `int`, and this member will be 0-initialized. But is that assumption based on solid grounds of standard?

Comment: Interesting. This produces the error in [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/467922a19099c9a7) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c8e5cba2847b829), but not with MSVC++. A side effect perhaps of [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)?

Comment: @flatmouse MSVC is buggy, as we all know :)

Comment: I think you mean full of extra and undocumented 'features' :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use (normally redundant) braces to avoid copy-initialization:

```
static t arr[2] = {{0}, {0}};
static std::array<t, 2> arr2 = {{{0}, {0}}}; /* Need extra pair here; otherwise {0} is
                                                treated as the initializer of the internal 
                                                array */
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efcf0badb7c04851). When omitting the braces, we're copy-initializing, which necessitates a temporary being created and copied from. With the braces, we have copy-list-initialization, which acts the same as direct-list-initialization (i.e. initializes each element with `{0}`, which is fine).

You can also wait until [guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) is introduced and just use your syntax.

Comment: Yes, I could do call_once, but there is no beauty in it. I'd love my syntax to be guaranteed :)

Comment: @SergeyA Your syntax is, as it stands, ill-formed. Some time will pass before the proposal I linked to becomes incorporated.

Comment: Well, what is this statement based on? That 0-initializing atomic is not going to 0-initialize my member? I am still upvoting for guranteed copy elision piece, and if nothing better comes out, I will accept for the same.

Comment: @SergeyA That is not guaranteed (zero-initialization means zero as the associated value). Of course you could just check your target implementation's code. It wouldn't be a hundred percent portable, though.

Comment: @SergeyA See my new answer.

Comment: Now that's a fantastic answer! I knew about this macro before, and I even tested it with `std::array` (it doesn't work with it), but it works with built-in array (which I didn't check)! For bonus, do you know why?

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry, I wasn't concentrated when I wrote this. My proposed syntax for plain arrays does not work for `array` directly, because aggregate initialization will treat {0} in {{0}, ...} as the initializer for the internal array itself, not the first element of it. That is, you will need an extra pair of braces to disambiguate.

Comment: Wonderful! I suppose, using macro instead of the **{}** is better? It says whether macro expands to **{}** or something else is implementation-defined, and, thinking about it, it would probably be something else exactly when my plain old 0-initialization won't work. Agree?

Comment: @SergeyA Nope. The macro exists merely for compatibility with C. My code is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to differentiate is default-initialization and zero-initialization. I have red about this very topic some time ago, and came to the conclusion that the standard implicitly requires the atomic-class to act identical to structs when it comes to initialization.

The non-atomic base type needs to be trivially copy-able, and the atomic type needs to both support default initialization and being initialized statically with (and without) `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`.
There aren't any any clean solutions I could come up with that don't end up using an inner struct or a deriving from a struct (I wrote an atomic implementation for a in-house RT OS).

So the standard if not requires, at least highly steers the implementation towards a solution where zero-initialization does exactly what you want.

I made a [Live Example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Ausing+t+%3D+std::atomic%3Cint%3E%3B%0A%0Avoid+ext(std::array%3Ct,+2%3E+%26)%3B%0A%0Avoid+foodefault()+%7B%0A++++std::array%3Ct,+2%3E+arr2%3B%0A++++ext(arr2)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+foozero()+%7B%0A++++std::array%3Ct,+2%3E+arr2%7B%7D%3B%0A++++ext(arr2)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+fooexplizit()+%7B%0A++++std::array%3Ct,+2%3E+arr2%7B%7B%7B0%7D,%7B0%7D%7D%7D%3B%0A++++ext(arr2)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) which compares the following:

```
std::array<t, 2> default;
std::array<t, 2> zero{};
std::array<t, 2> explicit{{{0},{0}}};
```

you will see that zero initialization is identical to the explicit version, and with gcc 6.3.0 even more efficient.

Just to reiterate, I don`t think the standard explicitly requires zero-initialization to behave that way, but - to my understanding - given what is defined it necessarily has to.

Answer (score -1):

From cppreference, documentation of the default constructor of std::atomic says:

> Constructs new atomic variable.
>
> 1) The default constructor is trivial: *no initialization takes place* other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects. std::atomic_init may be used to complete initialization.

So you will need Columbo's initialisation loop for sure.

Comment: Well, there is a 0-initialization taking place due to array being static. The question is, what 0-initializaion means for values inside atomics.

Comment: @SergeyA 0-initialisation, or default initialisation?

Comment: 0 initialization in this case. `static` does that for ya.

Comment: @SergeyA got it. §3.6.2 para 2 and §8.5 para 6